# jsf 2.0 f:convertDateTime for util.Date with using custom date pattern from .properties

Tags: jsf, date, datetime, jsf-2, converters

After changing locale in action mathod with return null as I apologize page should be reload but field with date doesn't change after first click on link for changing locale. I use MyFaces

I have a page where user can set locale and after changing locale I can't get desired format of date just after second time push on link for changing locale. I use bean for localization from this post

[localiztion article](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5388426/jsf-2-0-set-locale-throughout-session-from-browser-and-programmatically/5391493#5391493)

I cant understand why in

```
<h:outputText value="#{newsVar.date}">
<f:convertDateTime pattern="#{msg['date.pattern']}" />
</h:outputText>
```

***!!!! Edited!!!***
I have some problems with getting id of dataField whem I use facets in mainLayout.xhtml

```
<f:view locale="#{localeManager.language}">

            <div id="wrapper">
                <div class="header">
                    <ui:insert name="header">
                        <ui:include src="/pages/template/commonHeader.xhtml" />
                    </ui:insert>
                </div>
                <div class="content_container">
                    <ui:insert name="content" />
                </div>
            </div> 
</f:view>
```

commonHeader is included commandLink

```
    <ui:composition>
        <h:form>
            <h1>
                <h:outputText value="#{msg['header.text']}" />
            </h1>
            <div class="lang_selector">             
                <h:commandLink action="#{localeManager.changeLanguage('ru')}"
                    value="#{msg['header.language.ru']}">
<!--                    <f:ajax render=":listGroupId:dateField" />-->
                </h:commandLink>
                <h:commandLink action="#{localeManager.changeLanguage('en')}"
                    value="#{msg['header.language.en']}">
<!--                    <f:ajax render=":listGroupId:dateField" />-->
                </h:commandLink>
            </div>
        </h:form>
    </ui:composition>
```

And in current page I have next

```
<ui:composition template="/pages/layouts/mainLayout.xhtml">
        <ui:define name="content">
            <f:event type="preRenderView" listener="#{news.showNews}" />
            <h:form id="listForm" prependId="false">
                        <h:panelGroup id="listGroupId">             
                <ui:repeat var="newsVar" value="#{news.newsList}">
                    <div class="news_item">
                        <div class="news_title">
                            <h1>
                                <h:outputText value="#{newsVar.title}" />
                            </h1>
                            <div class="news_date">
                                <h:outputText id="dateField" value="#{newsVar.date}">
                                    <f:convertDateTime pattern="#{msg['date.pattern']}" />
                                </h:outputText>
                            </div>
```

As you can see a try to get id of "dateField" but that id in different form. I read next article [How to JSF 2.0: – render components outside of the form](http://ocpsoft.org/java/jsf2-java/how-to-jsf-2-0-render-components-outside-of-the-form/) I understand that I should set `<h:form id="listForm" prependId="false">` then I can set elementId in `<f:ajax/>` without name of form but I get error `javax.faces.FacesException - Component with id::listGroupId:dateField not found`.

And I find that: The element which is specified in render must be already present in the client side HTML DOM tree. May be that's why I have this problem

Please, help me...
Why is pattern for date changed only from 2nd time?

Comment: do you re render your `h:outputText` after you change the pattern ?

Comment: if I know rendered=true by default

Comment: I meant that after you "changing locale" you probably clicking on some button or other component , that button should have `f:ajax render="your_outputtext_idOryour_outputtext_wrapper_id"`...

Comment: I need a variant without ajax. Any other ideas?

Comment: you can reload the whole page (BAD) , otherwise I don't know how else you can reload from server , you need to call the `f:convertDateTime` , and you can't do it with client side... so you better use `f:ajax` , that's what the JSF2 is for...

Comment: I don't click after changing locale (just reload page) `<h:commandLink action="#{localeManager.setLanguage('en')}" value="#msg['header.language.en']}"/>` I have next link in header faclet of my page

Comment: @Daniel please, can you give me advice. I described appeared problem above

Comment: try to update a broader id , maybe some wrapper , do you use primeafes ? cause if yes, you can update by specifying css class name

Comment: Myfaces is a JSF implementation , while Primefaces is JSF Component Suite , http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7316611/icesfaces-vs-myfaces-vs-primefaces read balusC comment too... anyway try to find an id that you can reach in the render attribute , or think of redesign ...

Comment: @Daniel I think that problem not in re-rendering of the field. Problem with convertDateTime

Comment: if you think so, than try to create a super minimal example , and see if it works...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would recommend the following

1) change `setLanguage` into `changedLanguage` (inside that method set the language attribute)
in general , its a bad practive to use setters in action attribute , and in general use get/set prefix in actionmethods

2) add `f:ajax`

```
<h:commandLink action="#{localeManager.changedLanguage('en')}" value="#msg['header.language.en']}">
    <f:ajax render="dateField"/>
</h:commandLink>
```

3) change `h:outputText` into

```
<h:outputText id="dateField" value="#{newsVar.date}">
    <f:convertDateTime pattern="#{msg['date.pattern']}" />
</h:outputText>
```

Comment: May be it's a good solution but I can't do the same. I add some info in question above